# jquery selecting child elements on specific level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, select

i have a DOM something like

```
<ul>
 <li> list item </li>
 <li> list item </li>
 <li> has sub element
  <ul>
   <li> list item </li>
   <li> list item </li>
   <li> list item </li>
   <li> has sub element
     <ul>
      <li> list item </li>
      <li> list item </li>
      <li> list item </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li> list item </li>
</ul>
```

how can i get only first level li count except sum of all li elements which child ul elements have

Comment: If you have a id for the top most ul use it with child selector

`$('#mytopul > li').length`

Comment: if your first <ul> is first inside parent(body or div , whatever you ahve) , you can try `$('parentElement:first-of-type > li').length`

Comment: or another way is `$(li:not(ul ul li)).length`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CcQ69/4/

Answer (score 2):

Try [> child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) or [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
<ul id="FirstUL">
$('#FirstUL > li').length;
```

---

<strike>$('ul > li:not(:has(ul))').length;</strike>

---

[.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

> Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3YsVH/)</kbd>

```
var len = $('ul > li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).parents('ul').length == 1;
}).length;
```

---

Better Coed for that By Sir [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22047028/#comment-33427623)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3YsVH/)</kbd>

```
$('li:not(ul ul li)').length;
```

Comment: don't think the second solution works it will count all leaf `li` elements

Comment: Indeed, the second solution selects all the `li` elements without `ul` children, regardless of their parent...

Comment: The second solution will effectively select all "leaf nodes" in the tree, which may or may not be helpful.

Comment: @darkajax added a code that will do it without giving id.

Answer (score 0):

Or try

```
$("#ulID").children().length
```

which returns 4 in your case

Comment: Yeah but it is easily customizable if the poster can't really have an ID for <ul> :) Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of these:

```
$('ul:first > li').length;
$('ul:eq(0)').children('li').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should give an id or class to the first ul,
then you can use like

```
alert($(".classname").children("li").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please upvote if this helps you :)

https://api.jquery.com/children/

`jquery .children()` returns the immediate children of whatever element

So either you have the parent ul stored in a variable (which you should if this is a dynamic app, or if you're doing a lot of js on that element), OR you need to put an ID on that ul.  Then you simply use:

```
  $('#myId').children('li');
```

That gives you an array of four li's.

From there you can either get the length directly like so:

```
   $('#myId').children('li').length;
```

or  `var x = $('#myId').children('li');
      count = x.length;`

Comment: OP cannot upvote... Need >= 50 in rep ;)  BTW, should be: `$('#myId')`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('ul:first').children('li').length
```

Gives you a result of 4.

You can try it here - http://jsfiddle.net/rQWb3/